# MYSQL TIMESTAMP comparison

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I have a table with a column `Time` that stores a timestamp value, a column that stores a `Name` and a column that stores a `Status`.

I'm trying to find a query to update all entries before a given timestamp like this:

```
UPDATE `Table` 
SET Status=1
WHERE Name='personname' AND 'Time'<'2012-12-23 18:00:00'
```

The query is valid but nothing changes.

When trying to show the results of the `WHERE` part there are no results.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You're comparing the string literal `'Time'`:

```
'Time'<'2012-12-23 18:00:00'
```

Try comparing the time column instead:

```
Time < '2012-12-23 18:00:00'
```

Or if you have to, surround it in backticks:

```
`Time` < '2012-12-23 18:00:00'
```

[Live example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bf91b/6/0)

Comment: This worked like a charm. When I didn't qoute Time MYSQL would transfer it to a Uppercase string. Maybe it is a system used variable. The backticks solved it! Thanks~

Answer (score 3):

If you are sure about backticks and single quotes and still it doesnt work then try 
this out,

```
UPDATE `Table`SET Status=1
WHERE Name='personname' AND 
Time < STR_TO_DATE('2012-12-23 18:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
UPDATE `Table`SET Status=1
WHERE Name='personname' AND 
Time < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE('23-12-2012 18:00:00',' "%d-%m-%Y %h:%i:%s'));
```

Comment: Can you please briefly explain what changes have you made in the query and why, so that everybody could see your reasoning?